# Use Backblaze online backup with Ubuntu

Tags: backup, online-storage

I've read good things about [Backblaze](http://www.backblaze.com/) but unfortunately they don't seem to support Linux/Ubuntu.

Is *not supporting Linux* by Backblaze maybe not providing a nice GUI and it is still possible to use it for backup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, it seems to be a commercial decision.

See: https://help.backblaze.com/entries/20203476-Is-Backblaze-going-to-offer-Linux-support-

Answer (score -1):

[rclone](http://rclone.org/b2/), which is rsync or the cloud, supports Backblaze B2.